# I want to edit only one database field with one click with django

Tags: django, django-views

I have a Movie database and a boolean field init. I want to click a button and change that boolean field's value. But I couldn't manage to get Movie pk from the url. I'm getting this error: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'kwargs'

Here is my views:

```html
@login_required
def one_cikan_button(self, **kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs['pk']
    print(pk)
    film = Movies.objects.get(pk=pk)
    try:
        film.featured = False
        film.save()
        return redirect('/headoffice/onecikanlar/')
    except Exception as e:
        return redirect('/headoffice/onecikanlar/')
    return redirect('/headoffice/onecikanlar/')
```

My urls:

```html
    path('onecikanlar/kaldir/<pk>/', views.one_cikan_button, name="onecikankaldir"),
```

My template:

```html
<a href="/headoffice/onecikanlar/kaldir/{{obj.pk}}/" title="Sil"><i class="notika-icon notika-trash" style="font-size:14pt; color:black;"></i></a>
```

My models:

```html
class Movies(models.Model):


    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How can I solve this? Or can I use UpdateView with custom settings?

Comment: Any django view function gets called with the WSGIRequest as the first parameter. So if you defined your function with `self` as first parameter, I guess `self` is the `request` and `self.kwargs['pk']` doesn't make much sense. `pk = kwargs['pk']` would be correct (`pk = kwargs.get('pk')` would be better in case there isn't a pk) and replacing `self` with `request` would make more sense.

Comment: Since you know what you're passing to your view (the URL pattern guarantees that a `pk` will be passed), you should just define your view function like `def one_cikan_button(request, pk): ...`

Comment: Thanks. That solved my problem